# How to split data by character from a textbox to multicoloum and multiline in VB 6

Tags: split, vb6, multiline

i used VB 6 because my teacher challenged me to make a programm by VB 6.
i have data in textbox like this:
[image: the data is multiline and "." is dividing 3 type data, [data a].[data b].[data c] (enter)]

i want to split 3 type of that data to 3 coloums like a table. i know how to split that data by character using this type of code:

a = Split(Text1.Text, ".")(0)

and because i dont know how to make a table in VB 6, i split them to 3 textbox.
but its just splitting 1 line. the second line is not working.
[image: it just spliting the first line. another lines is not splitting :(]

this is my code:

```
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String

Private Sub Command1_Click()
a = Split(Text1.Text, ".")(0)
b = Split(Text1.Text, ".")(1)
c = Split(Text1.Text, ".")(2)
Text2.Text = a
Text3.Text = b
Text4.Text = c

End Sub
```

please help me.

Comment: ...isn't your teacher already a SO member?

Comment: @deblocker no, he's not :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use listbox instead textbox and then you can read and write line by line.

```
Private Function GetItemText(i As Integer) As String
   'Return the text of the item using the index:
   GetItemText = ListBox1.List(i)
End Function
```

Comment: thankyou for your suggest :) i used listbox like what you told me, but the code is not like that because that isn't vb6's code hehe but thankyouuuu

Comment: bruno, can you help me more? how about the result of splitting is not listbox but listed by listview? so listview have 3 coloum(a,b,c) 
please help me, thankyouu

Comment: you can create listbox with column: `ListBox1.ColumnCount = 3
ListBox1.Columnwidths = "100,100,100"
ListBox1.AddListItem("row1 col1", 1,1)
ListBox1.AddListItem("row1 col2", 1,2)
ListBox1.AddListItem("row1 col3", 1,3)
ListBox1.AddListItem("row2 col2", 2,2)`

Answer (score 0):

First, you must split lines, next you must split values by each line.
This should work:

```
Dim i as Long
Dim sLines() As String
Dim sValues() As String
sLines() = Split(Text1.Text, vbCrLf)
For i = 0 to UBound(slines)
    If sLines(i) > vbNullString Then ' skip for empty line
        sValues() = Split(sLines(i), ".")
        Text2.Text = Text2.Text & sValues(0) & vbCrLf
        Text3.Text = Text3.Text & sValues(1) & vbCrLf
        Text4.Text = Text4.Text & sValues(2) & vbCrLf
    End If
Next i
```

[image]

Comment: this code just splitting the last of list. so the first line is not show in the result. :(

Comment: See updated code. Ensure that all TextBoxs are set Multiline = True

Comment: giorgio, can you help me more? how about the result of splitting is not textbox but listed by listview? so listview have 3 coloum(a,b,c). i try to add item from text box to listview used  
code : ListView1.ListItems.Add , , Text2.Text 
but the result is not multi line

Comment: Use ListItems.Add for first value (1,2,3), but for the others values you use SubItems. The VB6 help file about listview control shows exactly how to. Anyway, if you have problems then open a new thread and shows your code.